# Flow Sends Email to Member and Supervisor Only

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

While I was waiting I went to the 'MemberList' and created an 'NotificationEmails' column that has the email addresses to which each notifications that meets the condition should be sent.

The content of the 'NotificationEmails' column looks like this: joe.noboby@emailcom, jane.random@email.com (the employee and the supervisor).

How do I incorporate the content (both email addresses) of the 'NotificationEmails' column from the 'MemberList' (for which I already have a Get items created in the flow), into the Send email of the flow so that ALL persons who have an email in the 'NotificationEmails' column of the 'MemberList' for the individual whose document will expire gets an email?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of add email address as text in column, we could add a **Person or Group** type column directly:

[image]

When you fill in users in this column, you can send emails to these users in the flow later.

[image]

In flow, we could select dynamic content: Person Email, this will send emails to all people that in that column:

[image]

Comment: How do I specifically identify the individuals to whom the email is to be sent? Currently, when I place a choice like 'Person Email' (or the contents of the 'NotificationsEmail' column/field I already have  - with the emails names for each person and their supervisor already in it), the flow generates one for every Member of the List (60 persons), instead of the two or three that should have been created based on the condition.

Comment: Please check the updated reply.

Comment: I am working from two different Lists - MemberList and MemberQualificationsList. The compliance issue and most of the email data is associated with the MemberQualificationList. The email addresses are on the MemberList, in the 'NotificationEmails' column. Both Lists have the 'MemberUniqueID'. How do I use the 'MemberUniqueID' to pull the contents of the 'NotificationEmails' from the MemberList so I can use the emaill addresses in the Send an email 'To:' field?

Comment: Never mind; it's not worth all the effort. I just added an email address column to the MemberQualificationList and grabbed it from there; thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear this is helpful to you.